# how to check no. of tries of task in push taskqueue in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I want to delete a task from task queue if the no. of tries is more than 5. How can I check the no. of tries in python?

Answer (score 0):

I want a task to try maximum 5 times. So I found a parameter to set in queue.yaml

```
queue:
- name: queue_name
  rate: 1/s
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 5
```

this is the link for complete documentaion

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue#Python_Configuring_retry_attempts_for_failed_tasks